# Why is HttpGet requiring parameter when it's marked as optional?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, model-view-controller, http-get

Basically, I have an Ajax method calling a controller HttpGet method. The controller method has two parameters, one is an enum and the other is an optional parameter which is a class object. However, upon making the request, it says that it requires the aforementioned optional parameter.

I have a HttpGet method as follows

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/api/getemployee(s)")]
        public ActionResult GetEditOrView(BaseAction action = BaseAction.GET, Employee? employee = null)
        {
            if (action == BaseAction.EDIT)
            {
                employee = employee ?? new Employee();
...
```

and an Ajax method as follows:

```
function getEditOrView(action, id = null){
        const employee = current_list.find((value) => value.EmployeeId = id);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/getemployee(s)",
            data: {action, employee},
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (action == @((int)BaseAction.GET)) {
                    current_list = result;
                    BindDataToTable(result);
                    return;
                }
                $('body').html(result);
            },
            fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            }
        });     
    }
```

When run in Postman, I get

```
{
    "errors": { \\ Fields of class Employee, reduced for the sake of compactness
        "City": [
            "The City field is required."
        ],
        "Email": [
            "The Email field is required."
        ],
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-561f327b8f50bb9287560b5ec1476d48-e2ec518b9f978d6d-00"
}
```

and in the browser network console

```
{"errors":{"":["A non-empty request body is required."]},"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-e6fd5a759763eac79eb2284b86be08a7-a1ec55fd1e78de10-00"}
```

Please help.

Comment: First of all, don't use parens in the route, it's just awful. Secondly, this really shouldn't be a GET if you're passing in a whole object. This is a really peculiar API endpoint.

Comment: @DavidG It's the same issue with HttpPost. And I have used HttpGet with an object as a parameter, and that works, however the parameter isn't optional there.

Comment: The employee itself is optional, but are the mentioned fields optional in the employee class?

Comment: @Developer No they aren't. But if the whole class parameter is optional, why should it matter if its members aren't?

Comment: @RuturajGole If you don't send an employee at all it should be fine, do you? How does the request atcually looks? Do you send an incomplete employee? BTW with employee being a reference type, why mark it as optional? Shouldn't it be null if not provided anyways?